# Swift: Value does not load to text field

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

When screen loads it gets the response from the REST call and then updates the UI.
Flow is working fine but somehow it is not updating the `textfield`'s values. Works fine for label.

**Label gets updated, textfield not.**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getContactInfo(id) //Rest call
}
```

> > Part of the rest call

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, responseData, error) -> Void in
                if let response = responseData as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                    self.statusCode = response.statusCode
                    print("Response code: \(response)")
                }

                do {
                    if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary {
                        //json parsing
                    }

                } catch {
                    print(error)

                }

                if(self.statusCode != 200) {
                    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
                }
                else {
                    let name = self.contact?.firstName
                    print("Everything Looks good: \(name!)")
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        self.updateUI()
                    })
                }
            }
            task?.resume()
      //  }

    }
```

> > Update UI

```
private func updateUI() {
        print("Refresh UI1")
        if contact != nil {
            print("Refresh UI2")
            self.firstName.text = (contact?.firstName)!
            self.name.text = (contact?.firstName)!
        }

    }
```

**Console Output**

```
Everything Looks good: Derp
Refresh UI1
Refresh UI2
```

> > **Note**: Is it the right way to do it?(I am new to iOS development)

Comment: Can you also post the console output, to check if the Refresh UI2 line is executed or not?

Comment: Yes, and seeing the declarations/values of contact and self.contact would probably help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper way how to update UI on async thread is as follows:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), { () -> Void in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        // Update UI
    })
})
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You meant like `else {
                    let name = self.contact?.firstName
                    print("Everything Looks good: \(name!)")
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), { () -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.updateUI()
        })
    })
                }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private func updateUI() {

 print("Refresh UI1")
        if contact != nil {
            print("Refresh UI2")
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
              self.firstName.text = (contact?.firstName)!
              self.name.text = (contact?.firstName)!
             }
           }
   }
```